# QGIS 3: Set custom project variables with input dialog

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt5, macro

I am using QGIS 3.10.0 and Windows 10. I have a project where I want the user to define custom project variables. I want to make this user friendly, I don't want the user to need to open the project settings.

So, I'm looking for a way where upon loading a project, an input dialog pops up in which the user can set custom project variables.

I've been trying to create a project macro and using PyQt5 to load an input dialog, but I keep getting error messages. I'm not a Python programmer, so I'm not even sure what I'm doing...

Could someone help me out and give me a hint on how to proceed?

**EDIT**
So I've added the code below to my project macro. Now whenever I launch the project, I get three seperate input dialogs. It works, but I would rather have one single dialog with three text fields. I know I have to use QDialog instead of QInputDialog, but I don't get it to work...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.core import QgsExpressionContextUtils, QgsProject

project = QgsProject.instance()

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Scherm'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.getToponiem()
        self.getOpdrachtgever()
        self.getProjectnummer()

        self.show()

    def getToponiem(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Toponiem","Toponiem:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'Toponiem',text)

    def getOpdrachtgever(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Opdrachtgever","Opdrachtgever:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'Opdrachtgever',text)

    def getProjectnummer(self):
        i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Projectnummer","Projectnummer:", 0, 0, 1000000, 1)
        if okPressed:
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'Projectnummer',i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def openProject():
    App()

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

**EDIT2**
I've been trying to call an QDialog when a project opens, but it doesn't work properly. The very simple code below does get executed but the dialog window opens and immediately closes again. How can I keep the dialog open until the user presses the button? (I will later fill the dialog with more options for the user to fill in).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton

def openProject():
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(500,500)
    button = QPushButton('OK')
    button.resize(200,32)
    button.move(80, 200)
    w.show()
```

Comment: I suggest you specify what you mean by "custom project variables". Is it just a name, or 15 popup-boxes, or what?

Comment: I'm talking about 3 different project variables (see my edit above).

Comment: So  can you share any code where you get stuck with QDialog?

Comment: @AndreasMüller I've edited my post to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You don't use QDialog in your example. Write a class by subclassing QDialog and insert the widgets you need. Then call this Dialog and its exec_-loop. There are excellent examples in the qt-documentation.